# IPhone Web App reurn to app after call

Tags: iphone, call

I have created a web app that produces a list of items to buy, It also gives a link to call the shop using a Tel: link to its phone number.

I want to stay on the app page during the call so the user can read the page out to the shop

Is that possible?

Answer (score 5):

nope, they'd have to open Safari up themselves while on the call.